# typedef for class member

Tags: c++, boost, typedef

Is it possible to do a typedef with class members / functions ? In the example below, I am using the boost bimap function to store information about the nearest neighbors of a node.

```
typedef boost::bimap<float /*distance*/, int /*id*/> neighbor_list;
neighbor_list node_a;

//fill up neighbors of node_a

//get nearest neighbor of node_a
node_a.neighbor.left.begin()->second;

//get distance to the nearest neighbor of node_a
node_a.neighbor.left.begin()->first;
```

The above lines however, looks messy and may not be intuitive. And so I was wondering if it is possible to do a `typedef` for class members so I could do something like the following

```
typedef boost::bimap<float /*distance*/, int /*id*/> neighbor_list;
typedef neighbor_list::left::begin()->first nearest_neighbor;

//nearest neighbor of node_a
node_a.nearest_neighbor;
```

I know I can write my own function that encapsulates the messy part of the code but I was wondering if I can give an alias to class members.

Comment: `typedef` is for types (what a surprise).  Functions are not types.

Comment: But you can wrap your intended behaviour in another function.  That would allow you to type `nearest_neighbor(node_a)`.

Comment: hi yes I am aware of that. I have yet to delve deep into C++ and so I was wondering if there is a way to do what I asked for

Comment: @Henri Menke thanks I guess functions are the simplest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delegate the nasty resolution to a function.

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap<float /*distance*/, int /*id*/> neighbor_list;

float nearest_neighbor(neighbor_list const& node)
{
  return node.neighbor.left.begin()->first;
}

void foo()
{
  neighbor_list node_a;

  nearest_neighbor(node_a);
}
```